# How to create data frame with links between data in two different data frames

Tags: python, pandas

I have one pandas dataframe for persons like:

```
pid   name   job
  1   Mike     A
  2   Lucy     A
  3   Jeff     B
```

And a second one for jobs like:

```
id    name
 1       A
 2       B
 3       C
```

What I want to produce is a third dataframe where I list the connections between people and jobs, so in this dummy example the desired result will be:

```
personid   jobid
       1       1
       2       1
       3       2
```

How can I accomplish this with pandas? I don't understand how to join in this case, since it's not a by row thing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with `pandas`, suppose you have df1 and df2:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.read_csv('Data1.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('Data2.csv')
print df1
print df2
```

df1 :

```
   pid  name job
0    1  Mike   A
1    2  Lucy   A
2    3  Jeff   B
```

and df2:

```
   id name
0   1    A
1   2    B
2   3    C
```

then:

```
df2['job']=df2['name']
df_result = df1.merge(df2, on='job', how='left')
print df_result[['pid','id']]
```

It will print out:

```
   pid  id
0    1   1
1    2   1
2    3   2
```

Comment: is there a way to make the comparison on 'job' a bit more intelligent? in my real life scenario, the strings don't match 100%

Comment: what do you mean for the string don't match 100%? if there is dirty data, you can clean it before you do the comparison. The merge have to got one shared key, which should be in both dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
output = pd.merge(persons, jobs, how='left', left_on='job', right_on='name')[['pid', 'id']]
```

Output:

```
   pid  id
0    1   1
1    2   1
2    3   2
```

Answer (score 0):

The two given dataframes are the following:

```
import pandas as pd
people_df = pd.DataFrame([[1, "Mike",  "A"], [2,  "Lucy", "A"], [3, "Jeff", "B"]], columns=["pid", "name", "job"])
jobs_df = pd.DataFrame([[1, "A"], [2,  "B"], [3,  "C"]], columns=["id", "name"])
```

You can get the desired result by using `merge` method.

```
merged_df = pd.merge(people_df, jobs_df, left_on='job', right_on='name')
result = merged_df[['pid', 'id']].rename(columns={'pid': 'personid', 'id': 'jobid'}) # for extracting and renaming data
```

"inner join" is used in default `merge` method. You can use `how` option for other "join" if you want.